# override/overwrite a function inside a function

Tags: javascript, prototype

Can you override/overwrite a function inside a function?
I have a function of which I can't change the code. I would like to change one of it's methods. I've tried the following, but it still alerts "parent init"

```
parent = function(arg){
    this.init = function(){
        alert("parent init")

    }  
    this.other = function(){
        alert('i just do this')           
    }
    // lots of other code that I would like not to have to copy paste

    this.init();  
}

child = function(arg){
    this.init = function(){
         alert("child init")
    }
}        

child.prototype = new parent();
child.prototype.init = function(){
    alert("another child init attempt")
}
child.init = function(){
    alert("another another child init attempt")
}

var x = new child();
```

Comment: That's because you're calling `this.init` immediately after assigning it: naturally that will be the value which is used. If you call `x.init()` afterwards, you should get "child init".

Comment: Also, you must be expecting `parent` to be called by `new child()` but that is not how prototypal inheritance works.

Answer (score 0):

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yXguc/

It is alerting from parent, because you are actually creating a new parent:

```
child.prototype = new parent();
```

Child init doesn't alert anything, because it doesn't call its own init. If you want parent's constructor to be executed, you have to call it manually.

```
var x = new child();
```